# algorithm of insert and merge integer to the nested array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6, lodash, reduce

I couldn't find the simple and readable way to solve it.

the operations on single element array like `[6]` in javascript is horrible...

### Question

originArray is a sorted, non-overlapping array.
and input is always a single positive integer.

if input number `4` is already inside `[[2,4],[7,8]]`, nothing will change.
if input number `13` is new to all ranges, it will insert it to the right, sorted position, like `[[2,4],[7,8],[13]]`

please help me with JavaScript native function (`reduce` prefer) or lodash.

Expected Behavior as below examples:

### Example 1

originArray `[[1,3],[7,10]]`

input `5`
output `[[1,3],[5],[7,10]]`

input `6`
output `[[1,3],[5,10]]`
6 is will connect 5 and 7, so make it [5,10].

input `13`
output `[[1,3],[5,10],[13]]`

### Example 2

originArray `[]`
input `3`
output `[[3]]`

input `4`
output `[[3,4]]`

input `2`
output `[[2,4]]`

input `7`
output `[[2,4],[7]]`

Comment: I cant figure out any input output relationship :) Feels like a puzzle :P

Comment: It feels like it's just a simple insert while maintaining sort for example 1, but `input 6 output [[1,3],[5,10]]` really throws me off.  The relationships here are very confusing.

Comment: @JosephMarikle originArray is like some ranges, if no ranges matchs input number , it will insert it to a new place, or auto-merge nearby ranges. (I edited my posts)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

```
function combineValues(originArray) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < originArray.length-1) {
    if (originArray[i+1][0] - originArray[i][originArray[i].length-1] <= 1) {
      // combine intervals
      var newInterval = [originArray[i][0], originArray[i+1][originArray[i+1].length-1]];
      originArray.splice(i, 2);
      originArray.splice(i, 0, newInterval);
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
}


function updateRanges(originArray, element) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= originArray.length; i++) {
    // if smaller than current range, insert new singleton or extend
    if (i === originArray.length || element < originArray[i][0]) {
      originArray.splice(i, 0, [element]);
      break;
    }
  }
  combineValues(originArray);
}


// testing
var updates = [3, 8, 7, 2, 9, 10, 1, 5, 6, 13];
var arr = [];

for (var u = 0; u < updates.length; u++) {
  updateRanges(arr, updates[u]);
  console.log(arr);
}
```

If you are concerned with the time complexity of your program, you can look into [binary searching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: @stackoverYC could you please explain what exactly fails?